# view 3: filter for datetime field is not working

Tags: views

I have created a customised module that export the content of a remote database tables to the view interface, every thing works fine except of the filter of the datetime field. In my file: mytable.views.inc

```
function mytable_views_data() {
  $data = array();
  $data['table1'] = array (
  'table' => 
   array (
    'group' => 'table1',
    'base' => 
     array (
      'field' => 'id',
      'title' => 'table1',
      'help' => 'table 1',
      'weight' => 10,
      'database' =>'database-name',
    ),
  ),
  'id' => 
   array (
    'title' => 'Id',
    'help' => 'Id',
    'field' => 
     array (
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_numeric',
      'help' => 'Id',
      'click sortable' => true,
    ),
    'filter' => 
    array (
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric',
      'allow empty' => true,
      'help' => 'Filter on <em class="placeholder">Id</em>',
    ),
    'argument' => 
    array (
      'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_numeric',
      'help' => 'Id',
    ),
    'sort' => 
    array (
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
      'help' => 'Sort by <em class="placeholder">Id</em>',
    ),
  ),

     'date' => 
      array (
      'title' => 'Date',
      'help' => 'Datetime field',
      'field' => 
       array (
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field', // I tried also 'views_handler_field_date' and 'views_handler_field_datetime' but view displays the message field handler is broken
      'help' => 'Date',
      'click sortable' => true,
    ),
    'filter' => 
     array (
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_date',
      'allow empty' => true,
      'help' => 'Filter on <em class="placeholder">Date</em>',
    ),
    'argument' => 
    array (
      'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_date',
      'help' => 'Date',
    ),
    'sort' => 
    array (
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort_date',
      'help' => 'Sort by <em class="placeholder">Date</em>',
    ),
  ),

);

return $data;
}
```

all the data fields are displayed properly in the view interface :[image]

and the filter of the field datetime is displayed also:
[image]

The problem is the filter have no effect on the datetime field, I tried to filter the field but the filter has no effect and the data was not filtered, I think that there is a non compatibility issue between the field handler and the filter handler but once I tried to use the field handler: 'views_handler_field_date' or 'views_handler_field_datetime', the views didnt displayed the data of the datetime field and it has indicated that the field handler is broken, and with the handler 'views_handler_field' every things is displayed well but the filter is not working!

Comment: what did you put in the value in value type as in above picture.

Comment: is between 2013-10-08 18:36:25 and 2013-10-08 18:36:30

Comment: Thank you but waiting for the answer I tried a solution and it is working :D I have added a  customised filter to my module that can handel datetime fields

Comment: Just for help, if any one find this must visit http://larsolesen.dk/node/273  Direct solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this handler **views_handler_field_date**, then uninstall and reinstall the module and try. Otherwise your changes will not affect.

Answer (score 0):

To allow `views_handler_field_date` to work with SQL datetime format, you can try:

- consider patch from [Drupal issue (#2178287)](https://www.drupal.org/node/2178287) which provides patch
- extend `views_handler_field_date` by your own (see [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/34417/1908)), e.g. by [JulienThomas](https://www.drupal.org/node/2178287#comment-10053900)

  ```
  class module_handler_field_datetime extends views_handler_field_date {
   function render($values) {
       $value = $this->get_value($values);
  return parent::render(strtotime($value)); 
   }
  }
  ```

  then add this file into .info file:

  ```
  files[] = handlers/module_handler_field_datetime.inc
  ```

  or check custom filter provided in this [blog](http://larsolesen.dk/node/273) ([gist](https://gist.github.com/lsolesen/897909)) as example:

  ```
  <?php
  /**
   * Custom filter handler for views, that handles DATETIME
   */
  class my_module_handler_filter_datetime extends views_handler_filter_date {
    function op_between($field) {
      if ($this->operator == 'between') {
        $a = intval(strtotime($this->value['min'], 0));
        $b = intval(strtotime($this->value['max'], 0));
      }
      else {
        $a = intval(strtotime($this->value['max'], 0));
        $b = intval(strtotime($this->value['min'], 0));
      }
      if ($this->value['type'] == 'offset') {
        // changed from original
        $a = (integer)time() + (integer)sprintf('%+d', $a); // keep sign
        $b = (integer)time() + (integer)sprintf('%+d', $b); // keep sign
        // changed from original ends
      }
      // %s is safe here because strtotime scrubbed the input and we might
      // have a string if using offset.
      $this->query->add_where_expression($this->options['group'], "$field >= '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $a)."'");
      $this->query->add_where_expression($this->options['group'], "$field <= '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $b)."'");
    }
    function op_simple($field) {
      $value = intval(strtotime($this->value['value'], 0));
      if (!empty($this->value['type']) && $this->value['type'] == 'offset') {
        $this->query->add_where_expression($this->options['group'], "$field $this->operator DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL $value SECOND)");
      } else {
        $this->query->add_where_expression($this->options['group'], "$field $this->operator $value");
      }
    }
  }
  ```

  or how it's implemented in [birthdays_field_views_handler_filter.inc](https://github.com/niklasf/birthdays/blob/7.x-1.x/views/birthdays_field_views_handler_filter.inc).